# A Voter and Votable User model with acts_as_votable plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the acts_as_votable plugin for Ruby on Rails. I only have a User model in my application and decided not to create a Profile model because the fields are limited. Is there a way to make the User both votable and a voter? My users should be able to create their profiles, vote up on other profiles with the exception of their own.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it looks like you should be able to do

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable
  acts_as_voter

  # ...
end
```

And then do

```
user1 = User.find(some_id)
user2 = User.find(some_other_id)

user1.liked_by user2
```